# Autoencoder model either oscillates or doesn't converge on MNIST dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

Already ran the code 3 months ago with intended results. Changed nothing. Tried troubleshooting by using codes from (several) earlier versions, including among the earliest (which definitely worked). The problem persists.

```py
# 4 - Constructing the undercomplete architecture
class autoenc(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nodes = 100):
        super(autoenc, self).__init__() # inheritence
        self.full_connection0 = nn.Linear(784, nodes) # encoding weights
        self.full_connection1 = nn.Linear(nodes, 784) # decoding weights
        self.activation = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.activation(self.full_connection0(x)) # input encoding
        x = self.full_connection1(x) # output decoding
        return x



# 5 - Initializing autoencoder, squared L2 norm, and optimization algorithm
model = autoenc().cuda()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                          lr = 1e-3, weight_decay = 1/2)



# 6 - Training the undercomplete autoencoder model
num_epochs = 500
batch_size = 32
length = int(len(trn_data) / batch_size)

loss_epoch1 = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_loss = 0
    score = 0. 


    for num_data in range(length - 2):
        batch_ind = (batch_size * num_data)
        input = Variable(trn_data[batch_ind : batch_ind + batch_size]).cuda()

        # === forward propagation ===
        output = model(input)
        loss = criterion(output, trn_data[batch_ind : batch_ind + batch_size])

        # === backward propagation ===
        loss.backward()

        # === calculating epoch loss ===
        train_loss += np.sqrt(loss.item())
        score += 1. #<- add for average loss error instead of total
        optimizer.step()

    loss_calculated = train_loss/score
    print('epoch: ' + str(epoch + 1) + '   loss: ' + str(loss_calculated))
    loss_epoch1.append(loss_calculated)
```

When plotting the loss now, it oscillates oscillates wildly (at lr = 1e-3). Whereas 3 months ago, it was steadily converging (at lr = 1e-3).

Can't upload pictures yet due to recently created account.

[How it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzDnV.png)

Though this is when I reduce the learning rate to 1e-5. When it's at 1e-3, it's just all over the places.

[How it should look like, and used to look like at lr = 1e-3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ugR7.png)

Comment: You should do `optimizer.zero_grad()` before you do `loss.backward()` since the gradients accumulate. This is most likely causing the issue.

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you!!! How do I give you an upvote or reputation? Though just out of curiosity; was this recently changed in pytorch?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, you can accept that. No, I don't think it was recently changed, this has been standard for quite some time.

Comment: Nevermind. Added the optimizer.zero_grad() but what happened instead is that it seems like the loss is barely changing at all and ends up at 0.35 (far from around 0.14 where it used to be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do `optimizer.zero_grad()` before you do `loss.backward()` since the gradients accumulate. This is most likely causing the issue.

The general order to be followed during training phase :

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
output = model(input)
loss = criterion(output, label)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Also, the value of weight decay used (1 / 2) was causing an issue.

Comment: Setting optimizer.zero_grad() was definitely part of the solution. For anyone in the future who might struggle with the part where the convergence seems to have stopped; what fixed the issue for me was to get rid of the weight decay. Now it works!

Comment: Okay, I'll add that in the answer too. You could try using lower values for the weight decay like 1e-4 or 1e-5 rather than the 0.5 you were using earlier.